# Clarification on numeric formatting

Tags: delphi, signed, formatting

I have a couple questions regarding the following code from the book [Delphi Foundations](http://delphifoundations.com/)

```
S := Format('It is %d', [65]); //assigns it to 64
```

1. Is 64 a typo?
2. Why does `S := Format('%u', [-1]);` return `4294967295`?

Comment: There are three questions here. Please ask one at a time. Please ensure that the question is complete. Don't refer to resources that you cannot link to. If you are going to quote code, be 100% certain that you transcribe it correctly. The code in the question does not compile. Finally, if you want to know what "lay person" means, this is the wrong site. I suggest you look that up in a dictionary.

Comment: I removed the signature from your question body. Questions are automatically signed. You don't need to, and should not, do it manually.

Comment: 'Put on hold as unclear what you're asking'? What rubbish, though the person (not the OP) who completely edited out the name of my book didn't help. If you want to ignore my answer because of my special relation to the subject then fine, however Remy Lebeau gave a perfectly good answer too, and before I did.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston Close reason is bogus, as is often the case. Should be "Too Broad". Original question asked three distinct questions. There should be only one question asked at a time.

Answer (score 3):

1. `S := Format('It is %d', [65])` will produce `'It is 65'`. If the book says otherwise then it is wrong.
2. `S := Format('%u', [-1])` produces `'4294967295'` because the number is being formatted as an **unsigned** value.  Signed `-1` has the same bit pattern as unsigned `4294967295` (they are both `$FFFFFFFF` in hex).
3. [Lay person](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lay+person?s=t)

Answer (score 2):

(1) Typo - see http://delphifoundations.com/errata/ for that one and more (and if you spot any others yourself, I would be grateful for the feedback).

(2) For the reason I say in the book:

> If a signed integer is passed, it is simply cast to an unsigned
>   integer. Given the way a signed integer is represented internally,
>   this will not just strip off the sign from a lay person’s point of
>   view. E.g., `Format('%u', [-1])` returns '4294967295', not '1'. If just
>   stripping off the sign is what you want, then pass the value to the
>   `Abs` standard function first: `Format('%u', [Abs(-1)])`.

So, take an Integer/Int32 and a Cardinal/UInt32: an instance of both these types takes 32 bits of memory. In the case of Integer/Int32 however, one of those bits is used to record the sign (plus or minus?), whereas with a Cardinal/UInt32, there is no sign to record; instead, that same bit is used to allow representing a number much bigger than an Integer/Int32 can represent. As such, the internal representation of Int32(-1) happens to be the same as the internal representation of UInt32(4294967295).

(3) 'Lay person' in this context is just a synonym for 'non-technical person', 'someone who isn't a geek', etc.